# id integer, auto increment, and PRIMARY KEY is null in database

Tags: flutter, sqflite

### I am creating database for todo application, i made id integer, auto increment, and PRIMARY KEY, But it stored on database null!

**the stored database is:**

- I/flutter ( 2705):  print all Data [{id: null, content: l will go
  home, status: today, isFinished: false}, {id: null, content: buy tea,
  status: today, isFinished: true}]

**the code is:**

```
class DBHelper {
  DBHelper._();
  factory DBHelper() => instance;
  static final DBHelper instance = DBHelper._();
  Database? _db;

  Future<Database> _createDB() async {
    if (_db != null) return _db!;
    String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'todo.db');
    _db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database database, int version) {
      return database.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE tasks (id integer auto increment PRIMARY KEY ,content TEXT,status varchar(15),isFinished BOOLEAN) ");
    }, onOpen: (_) {
      print("\n opened \n ");
    });
    return _db!;
  }

  Future<int> insertNodeToDB(NoteDatabaseModel noteDatabaseModel) async {
    Database _database = await _createDB();
    return _database.rawInsert(
            'INSERT INTO tasks (content,status,isFinished)values("${noteDatabaseModel.content}", "${noteDatabaseModel.status}","${noteDatabaseModel.isFinished}")');
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just returning the data you inserted and not the row itself. You will need to run an inline select statement to return the row you inserted with it's generated id, something like this should work

```
Future<int> insertNodeToDB(NoteDatabaseModel noteDatabaseModel) async {
    Database _database = await _createDB();
    var result = _database.rawInsert(
            'INSERT INTO tasks (content,status,isFinished)values("${noteDatabaseModel.content}", "${noteDatabaseModel.status}","${noteDatabaseModel.isFinished}"); SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id = last_inserted_row_id();');
    Return result;
    }
```

last_inserted_rowid() is a function to return the last generated id.